# How do I pass an object property to an event handler function in order to perform DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I have an HTML page rendered using React. I've retrieved a list of objects representing websites and stored them in memory, and can display them in a long list on the page just fine.

I've added a button for each object rendered on the page. I've created an event handler for the `onClick` that should receive a property from the object (`uid`), then generate a new table on the page with details specific to that object.

I think I'm missing something crucial in React, because I can't seem to pass the object data to the event handler.

**HTML/JSX**

```
   <div>
        <h2>results</h2>
        <ul>
          {countriesToShow.map((x, i) => {
            let uid = x.uid;
            return (
              <li key={i} id={i}>
                {x.name.common}{' '}
                <button onClick={toggleShowCountry(uid)}>show</button>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
```

**toggleShowCountry**

```
const toggleShowCountry = (x) => {
    console.log('this is uid', x);
    // TODO: get DOM object where the country resides and manipulate it
  };
```

**Output**

Nothing. Not even undefined. Clicking the button doesn't cause anything to appear in the console, and on the initial render it looks like `toggleShowCountry` fires automatically for each object as it is rendered.

I believe this might have somethign to do with the "bind" feature of JavaScript but am not totally sure.

Comment: You're looking for: `<button onClick={() => toggleShowCountry(uid)}>show</button>` What you have in the question is **calling** the function and using its return value as a click handler. Instead, create a function that, when run, will call your function with the relevant value.

Comment: This is already **well** covered by previous questions and answers, so I suggest just deleting it.

Comment: It’s because you’re calling it during render; that’s what the `()` does. Use an anonymous function; `onclick={() => toggleShowCountry(uid)}`

Comment: thank you all, I understand my issue now. It looks like stackoverflow strongly advises against deleting questions unless they're exposing identifying details

Answer (score -1):

try this one:
`<button onClick={() => toggleShowCountry(uid)}>show</button>`